# Prism PopupWindowAction causes error in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, prism-5

I am using the PopupWindowAction from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity'

When I build my application the build succeeds and the application runs and works correctly however I loose designer support for my view due to the following error:

The type 'PopupWindowAction' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project

This issue did not occur in visual studio 2013.  Can anyone suggest how I resolve the issue?

Comment: same issue for me, I've upgraded PrismLib to v6 but nothing changed

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I ended up posting an issue to the Prism team on github:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/213

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and I finally resolved this by reinstalling Visual Studio 2015. I did this after realizing that my colleagues did not experience the same behavior.